# Issue with redirect vs render from a ajax jquery call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

This is what my js looks like,

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/traffic/validateParams",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (d) {
        if(d == "") {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/traffic/update",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            });
        } else {
            alert(d);
            btn.removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    }
});
```

Here, validateParams will return an error message if something is incorrect with the validation of the data, or else update method is called.

My issue starts here, with the update method. Below are two codes for the same method, the one with redirect doesnt work, and the one with render works just fine.

Code with redirect:

```
def update() {
    def p = (request.JSON ?: params)?.subMap(TrafficSimulatorConstant.params.keySet())
    TrafficSimulatorConstant.updateParams(p)
    log.info("traffic simulator configured")
    redirect(action: "status") }
```

Here, in the above code, even though the values are update, there is no redirect to the status page. and also, the button is not enabled.

Code with render:

```
def update() {
    def p = (request.JSON ?: params)?.subMap(TrafficSimulatorConstant.params.keySet())
    TrafficSimulatorConstant.updateParams(p)
    log.info("traffic simulator configured")
    String url = createLink(action:"status")
    render(text: "window.location.href='${url}'", contentType: "application/javascript") }
```

Here, the values are update and the page is redirected to the status page. The button enable/disable doesn't matter because it is a page redirect and we have a new page.

I would like to understand the difference between the two implementations and also would like to know if there is a way to achieve the same behavior with redirect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post your HTML and Angularjs codes for button click handling.

Comment: i doubt, the `click` event is not properly handled. Does it really redirect to given url in `${url}` or to other location?

Comment: i am afraid, 2nd example is not a good way to `redirect`.